# Using Google Earth API to find the structure of a landscape

Tags: javascript, navigation, google-earth-plugin

I am looking to use the [Google Earth API](http://code.google.com/apis/earth/documentation/reference/#) to help one of my robots navigate around big obstacles (such as buildings).

Is there any way to get information on the structure of buildings/features (such as trees) that Google Earth renders through the Javascript API?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can achive this via hit-testing - the `GEHitTestModeEnum` `GEPlugin.HIT_TEST_BUILDINGS` may be suitable for your needs - although the actual accuracy in the real world may not be high enough for you. Calculating a 'buffer zone' around you robot would be the best bet.

Here is the GEView hit-test documentation

https://developers.google.com/earth/documentation/reference/interface_g_e_view#a8e8274c1236b6bbeff60a7a74e15995c

Here is a working hit-test example.

http://earth-api-samples.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/examples/hittest.html